# Help Identifying my cactus

Tags: identification, cactus

He seems to grow with others, has white areoles with tiny, but harmless spikes. He's around 2-3 inches tall, but is getting a little bigger every few months. I have closer up pictures, but they won't post. [image]

Comment: Welcome, have you tried an app like plantNet?

Comment: How many spines are there per areole? In what kind of an arrangement? For example, if four spines, are they two up/two down, with the spines spread out a bit? Closeups should post just like the photo you've posted.